# Informatica control file path using loader connection

Tags: informatica

How can i view the path where the control file gets generated,because ctl file is not getting generated for one of my mload connection for teradata. How can i change it?

```
However, in the session log i can see it in some /app/.... directory.Does it get copied from that path to my unix mount point?
```

I am using teradata mload loader connection.

Regards, 
Amit

Comment: Read the log file, it should be somewhere in top lines. Or paste top ~30 rows here - perhaps someone would be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could check powercenter integration service process properties (On Informatica's Adminconsole, go to  that particular integration service > process > here all the log specific location variables are set) or, you can check the session properties of your loader in powercenter client. If it still doesn't help you out, elaborating more on your question might fetch you the concrete answer.